# CONSTRUTOR PARA METODO EM PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, método, instanciar-objeto

Gostaria de saber se há algum método magico equivalente a construtores e destrutores de objeto , mas para métodos.

Exemplo ao chamar o método teste() do objeto padeiro eu gostaria de executar outro método para setar atributos, e ao objeto ser finalizado outro método também para registro.

Estou fazendo um objeto quero fazer métricas de performance.

como o __call()  que é chamado quando o método não existe.

a ideia é sempre registrar log's de tempo de execução e consumo de memoria.

```
class padeiro{
 public function teste(){
    echo'processamento aleatorio';
 }

 public function metodo_magico_construtor(){
 //grava atributos para metricas
 } 
 public function metodo_magico_destrutor(){
 //grava atributos para metricas
 }

}

$obj = new padeiro();
$obj->teste();
```

Preciso que quando o método seja chamado seja executado as funções complementares.

$obj->teste();
metodo_magico_construtor();
ai sim o
teste();
e em seguida o
metodo_magico_destrutor();

Estou perguntando pois acabei não encontrando informações sobre o tema na minha pesquisa na internet e na documentação do php mais a titulo de curiosidade a fim de saber se existe algo a respeito na própria linguagem.

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

Em PHP, não há uma forma de criar um método mágico para ser chamado automaticamente antes ou depois de um outro método ser executado. No entanto, você pode criar os métodos manualmente e chamá-los no início e no final do método que deseja medir. Por exemplo:

```
class Padeiro
{
    public function teste()
    {
        $this->registrarInicio(); // Chamada do método de registro de início de execução

        echo 'processamento aleatório';

        $this->registrarFim(); // Chamada do método de registro de fim de execução
    }

    private function registrarInicio()
    {
        // Código para registrar o início da execução do método teste()
    }

    private function registrarFim()
    {
        // Código para registrar o fim da execução do método teste()
    }
}

$obj = new Padeiro();
$obj->teste();
```

Outra opção é usar uma biblioteca de medição de desempenho, como o Xdebug, que permite medir o tempo de execução e o uso de memória de uma função ou método em particular. Você pode habilitar o Xdebug e usar suas funções de medição de desempenho para medir o método teste() da seguinte maneira:

```
xdebug_time_index(); // Inicia a medição de tempo

$obj = new Padeiro();
$obj->teste();

echo xdebug_time_index(); // Exibe o tempo de execução do método teste()
```

Espero que isso ajude! Qualquer dúvida adicional, não hesite em perguntar.